# Traveling with separate tickets from India through Oman and Turkey to Sweden

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, turkey, oman, self-transfer

I'm an Indian who is working in Sweden. I have an Indian passport and Swedish residence permit. I'm currently in India for vacations and I would like to book my return tickets. I saw this nice deal where I get a cheaper ticket (3200 sek) if I book a ticket with separate check-in. Through India to Oman, Oman to Turkey and then Sweden.

I have never done this before. **Do we need a "Transit" visa for Turkey or Oman in this case?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If, as I understand it, each of the three flights is booked separately, then yes, you will need a visa for both Oman and Türkiye.

Apparently in your situation you should be able to get eVisas for both rather than having to visit the respective local visa processing centres.

Remember, though, that if you miss a connection you are on your own to rebook and pay for a new ticket (at last minute prices, which can sometimes be very expensive), so make sure you have **a lot** of margin.

Comment: Its often not worth it with visas and other expenses.